WooCommerce PHP script sometimes working, sometimes not
I built a WooCommerce plugin that, among other things, allows a customer to order a sample of the product they are currently viewing. Sometimes this functionality works, sometimes it does not. I am able to see the data come all the way through to the functions.php, but I cannot figure out why some products add a sample to the cart and others don't. Before I share the relevant code, keep in mind that the sample is an actual product in the WooCommerce admin area. The sample sku is based upon the product sku.
functions.php
add_action('wp_ajax_order_sample', 'order_sample');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_order_sample', 'order_sample');

function order_sample() {  
  $cart_item_key = null;
  
  if ((isset($_POST['nonce']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'nonce_custom_atc'))
  && (isset($_POST['product_id']) && $_POST['product_id'] > 0)
  && (isset($_POST['quantity']) && $_POST['quantity'] > 0)
  && (isset($_POST['cost']) && $_POST['cost'] > 0)) {
    $cart_item_key = wc()->cart->add_to_cart(
      intval($_POST['product_id']),
      intval($_POST['quantity']),
      0,
      array(),
      array(
        'cost'=>isset($_POST['cost']) ? floatval($_POST['cost']) : '',
        'thumbnail_url'=>isset($_POST['thumbnail_url']) ? esc_attr($_POST['thumbnail_url']) : '',
        'sku'=>isset($_POST['product_sku']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['product_sku']) : '', // we do this to specifically set the sku on the order to the sample sku and NOT the product sku
      )
    );
  }
  write_log(create_message('sku: ' . $_POST['sku'])); // lets us confirm that the info came through from the AJAX call
  wp_die(isset($cart_item_key) && $cart_item_key ? "Added to cart!" : "Error: not added!");
}

function write_log($message) {
    $logger = wc_get_logger();
    $logger->debug($message, array('source' => 'visualizer'));
}

function create_message($item) {
  return boolval(!empty($item)) ? print_r($item, true) : 'nothing to see here!';
}

visualizer-modal.php
global $product;
$id = trim($product->get_id());
  
$sku = trim($product->get_sku());
$sample_sku = "";
$product_sku = "";

if (str_starts_with($sku, "S-")) {
  $sample_sku = $sku;
  $product_sku = str_replace("S-", "", $sku);
} else {
  $product_sku = $sku;
  $sample_sku = "S-" . $sku;
}
// this lets us make sure that we get the sample sku and the product sku into the right places
  
$sample_id = trim($GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results("SELECT `product_id` FROM `wp_wc_product_meta_lookup` WHERE `sku` = '" . $sample_sku . "'")[0]->product_id);

<div class="hidden" id="sample-sku">
  <?php echo esc_attr($sample_sku) ?>
</div>
<div class="hidden" id="sample-id">
  <?php echo esc_attr($sample_id) ?>
</div>
<div class="hidden" id="thumbnail-url">
  <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url($cart_thumbnail, 'full') ?>
</div>

js/order-sample.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (typeof wc_params_custom === 'undefined') {
    return false;
  }

  const ORDER_SAMPLE_BUTTON = document.getElementById('order-sample');
  const SAMPLE_SKU = document.getElementById('sample-sku').innerHTML.trim();
  const SAMPLE_ID = document.getElementById('sample-id').innerHTML.trim();
  const CART_THUMBNAIL_URL = document.getElementById('thumbnail-url').innerHTML.trim();
  const GOLD_COLOR = '#DEC48D';
  const COST = 5;

  ORDER_SAMPLE_BUTTON.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const ORDER = {
      action: 'order_sample',
      nonce: wc_params_custom.nonce,
      product_id: SAMPLE_ID,
      product_sku: SAMPLE_SKU,
      quantity: 1,
      cost: COST.toFixed(2),
      thumbnail_url: CART_THUMBNAIL_URL,
    };

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: wc_params_custom.ajax_url,
      data: ORDER,
      success: (response) => {
        console.log('response: ', response);
        ORDER_SAMPLE_BUTTON.innerHTML = 'Added to Cart!';
        ORDER_SAMPLE_BUTTON.style.backgroundColor = GOLD_COLOR;
        setTimeout(() => {
          location.reload();
        }, 1000);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.error('error: ', error);
      },
    });
  });
});

I have also checked and double-checked the sample products in the WooCommerce admin area and cannot see any difference in how the non-working samples are setup versus the working samples. All of the same fields are filled out, the same radio buttons clicked, etc. However, something is obviously wrong because the same code will add some samples to the cart, but not others.
Does anybody have any idea of what isn't quite right here? Thanks for your time!

Note that in your JavaScript, $ alias is not defined in $.ajax and should be replaced with jQuery.ajax…

Would it not perhaps make more sense, if you wrote a little code to determine what the appropriate sample product for the currently viewed "real" product is - and then used the "Add to Cart" or "Add to Cart URL" shortcodes in your product page template, to let WooCommerce handle the actual adding of the sample into the card, using its default mechanisms?

Sorry for the late response, crazy weekend. However, after giving both a try, neither of these worked for my situation.

I figured out what the issue is. Somehow, in my client's Adminer DB, some sample products had two IDs associated with them and others only one ID. The ones that didn't add to the cart had two. If anybody else runs into a similar issue, check the wc_product_meta_lookup table to be sure.
